# PrimeFaces Barcode sample

Tags: jsf, primefaces, barcode

I just tried to just copy-paste sample from PrimeFaces Showcase about Barcode.
Here is this code, and I get:

[image]

I just wanted to test it go get same effect as sample.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  


<h:head> 
</h:head>  

<h:body>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:outputText value="Postnet" />
        <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="postnet"/>

        <h:outputText value="QR" />
        <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="qr"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you add barcode4j and qrgen library into your dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**barcode4j 2.1 does not exist in maven central repository so manual installation is necessary for
maven users

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a jar file to your repository to let primefaces understand the component much better. You can get the jar from here http://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/barcode_symbologies. That is the "barcode4j-light version 2.1"